# Problems with Django Template and Json Data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I get `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error on the page when my cart is empty but works when cart is populated. I'm expecting the error but that doesn't help either. Same continues on the other template also if data is empty. Maybe it has to do something not being returned.

```
def cartdetails(request):
    if request.session.get('token', None) != None:
        tokenid = request.session.get("token")
        headers = {'Authorization': 'token ' + str(tokenid[0])}

        url = 'https://api-ecommerce.datavivservers.in/mobile_api/CartDetails/'
        jsondata = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
        print(jsondata)
        try:
            return render(request, 'cart.html', {
            "order_id": jsondata['order_id'],
            "user_id": jsondata['user_id'],
            "wallet_amount": jsondata['wallet_amount'],
            "payable_amount": jsondata['payable_amount'],
            "payment_status": jsondata['payment_status'],
            "payment_mode": jsondata['payment_mode'],
            "order_status": jsondata['order_status'],
            "delivery_status": jsondata['delivery_status'],
            "order_delivery_type": jsondata['order_delivery_type'],
            "get_cart_total_discount": jsondata['get_cart_total_discount'],
            "get_cart_total_GST": jsondata['get_cart_total_GST'],
            "get_cart_total": jsondata['get_cart_total'],
            "get_cart_sub_total": jsondata['get_cart_sub_total'],
            "get_cart_quantities": jsondata['get_cart_quantities'],
            "get_cart_items": jsondata['get_cart_items'],
            "deliveryCharges": jsondata['deliveryCharges'],
            "subscription_type": jsondata['subscription_type'],
            "subscriptionId": jsondata['subscriptionId'],
            "products": jsondata['products']
        })
        except simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError:
            return render(request, 'cart.html', {})
    else:
        print("login")
        return redirect('login')
```

Comment: why dont you just check for empty values and catch the errors before they are raised.

Comment: are you sure you are catching it? what does the print(jsondata) give you when empty?

Comment: You are not catching the error `jsondata = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()`. This line is where you do the conversion to json, it is not in the try block.